# How do I remove or customize the border around an Access form's navigation button that is selected?

Tags: forms, ms-access, button

[image]

When the user clicks a navigation button, the button has a dashed border. I want to either remove the border or customize the line type or color. I've modified a few of the items in the Properties window, but nothing worked. I'm looking for either the Property that I can set on the form or with VBA. Thanks.

It looks like if I click the button, the border appears. When I click elsewhere, the border disappears. I'm wondering if this is just default Windows or Access behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about a command button control? AFAIK, this feature cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks. I just added an image to the original question, and provided more details in the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design, but you can redesign the buttons for this "feature" to be less disturbing:

[Modern/Metro style message box and input box for Microsoft Access 2013+](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17684/Modern-Metro-style-message-box-and-input-box-for-Microsoft-Access-2013.html)

If you have no account, browse for the link: Read the full article.

Code is also on **GitHub**: [VBA.ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox)